# Can't Open SQL DTS Packages

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

We have a SQL 2008 server. When trying to open DTS packages we'd get this error:

"SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer components are required to edit DTS packages."

Installing SQL Server 200 DTS Designed got rid of this error, but now we get this:

"here were errors loading package "C:\Test\BIData.dts":
The specified file is not a Package Storage File. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsObjectExplorerUI)"

We've tried with a couple DTS packages. Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when first attempting to maintain DTS packages using the SQL Server 2008 tools (they weren't worth the effort of converting to SSIS, but still necessary for business reasons.)

There are a couple of MSDN articles I found helpful:

- [How to: Install Support for Data Transformation Services Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755.aspx) contains all the steps needed to get DTS Designer working in the SQL Server 2008 management tools
- [Support for SQL Server 2000 DTS in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx) is a good general overview of considerations for managing DTS packages in SQL Server 2008.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Server 2008 – MUST INSTALL IN THIS ORDER

Install the DTS Designer Components (this must be installed first so that the correct system `PATH` is configured correctly)

1. If Windows 8 – must install .NET 3.5 components via Programs & Features
2. Install SQL Server 2008 client tools (complete)
3. Install SQL Server 2005 Backwards Compatibility Pack
4. Replace the `stardds.dll` file

Comment: 6 years later I don't have access to this project anymore. Heck, I don't even remember it. :) But if someone can confirm that they were getting the same error message I was getting and this answer solves it I'll happily mark this as the accepted answer.